# Sequel Dataset Aggregate Count

Tags: ruby, dataset, aggregate, sequel

I'm trying to count the fields in a table, and the returned SQL isn't generated properly.

What am I doing wrong?

`ds` is the dataset:

```
term = 'abouts'
puts ds.count(:id).where(kind: term)       # => app.rb:179:in `<main>': undefined method `where' for 115:Integer (NoMethodError)
```

I am thinking aggregate methods can have conditionals like `WHERE`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You're getting an error because you're adding a query to the result of a count, which Ruby knows is a syntax error, and therefore it becomes an off-topic question. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages and "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)" especially the last one.

Comment: If you read the `Sequel` documentation, queries can be added anywhere.  The question was valid.  How can a resulting error be an off-topic question?  It __IS__ the question.

Answer (score -1):

Found it:

```
puts ds.where(kind: term).count
```

Comment: Looks like a query and a count to me.  Not sure why it's got a -1 either.  It IS the answer to a valid question.  Oh right, SO.